# How to find source of unwanted FPS counter overlay

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

Since a few days, I have an fps counter on the top right part of the screen. Just a yellow number, always present (even when not in a game etc, appears shortly after login, and does not disappear until the screen goes blank on shutdown).

I've failed to figure out what puts it there. I have found very few clues in the moment I first noticed it: a game was stuck on a strange resolution, and I updated the NVidia graphics driver thinking that was maybe the cause of the games strange selection of resolution.

I've checked the settings of all application that I know or could find might do this, although most would normally only do it in games, and only when they are running: steam, fraps, NVidia's Geforce Experience (which I did not have installed, but thinking it was a driver settings set via that, I installed it to be sure), and I tried to downgrade the NVidia driver again.

I've tried to use spy++ to see if it detects the thinking as a form of window and can tell me the process, it doesn't see a window at that spot (only what is underneath the counter). I've tried [Rotihab api monitor](http://www.rohitab.com) to find an application drawing somehow, but no luck so far (I'm new to that, so I may be doing something wrong).

My best guess is still something in the NVidia driver, because it shows even when all applications are closed, and the applications I know that do this usually only do so when they are running (e.g. fraps, steam). However I've not been able to find anything about this, searches always end up with the GeForce Experience app.

What else can I do to find what is drawing it? Or any other apps that do this sort of thing that I need to check?

Windows 10 21H1, GTX1660Ti, NVidia drivers back to 516.94 (after the downgrade from 527.56).

Comment: It's either through the GeForce Experience or the launcher/store overlay.  The Nvidia driver itself cannot display a FPS overlay.  Boot to a minimal boot configuration and see if the FPS overlay is still displayed. A screenshot of the FPS counter, and whatever overlay (Steam, Epic, etc.) does work, would be helpful.

Comment: Check the OSD settings for your monitor.

Comment: @Yorik - A screenshot would oddly confirm if its OSD of the monitor, since the FPS counter would not be visible in such a screenshot

Comment: That was a great and correct idea @Yorik, tyvm! And good point Ramhound, a screenshot would have confirmed it, I just never thought about it not being software!

Comment: If it was the monitor, you should add your own answer confirming it. It is OK to answer your own question (and accept that answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hints in the comments I found a setting in the monitor that shows an FPS counter. I would have never thought of it!